Hypothesis tests in summary of glm() are always Wald tests?
The summary output of glm() in R uses t-statistic when dispersion is estimated and z-statistic when dispersion is not estimated. I want to know if both tests are called the Wald test. I know there are related posts (link, link), but I was not very sure. If both are Wald tests, it is fine. But if one of them is not a Wald test, how do I report the results (i.e., I need to tell the name of the hypothesis test)?
> set.seed(10)
> x <- runif(10,0,10)
> y <- rpois(10,0.1+0.1*x)
> plot(x,y)
> 
> summary(glm(y~x,family=poisson))

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ x, family = poisson)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  -3.7188     2.1062  -1.766   0.0775 .
x             0.5385     0.3727   1.445   0.1486  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 7.2238  on 9  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 4.7562  on 8  degrees of freedom
AIC: 14.756

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

> summary(glm(y~x,family=quasipoisson))

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ x, family = quasipoisson)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  -3.7188     1.6220  -2.293   0.0510 .
x             0.5385     0.2870   1.876   0.0975 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for quasipoisson family taken to be 0.5930236)

    Null deviance: 7.2238  on 9  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 4.7562  on 8  degrees of freedom
AIC: NA

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

> summary(glm(y~x,family=gaussian))

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ x, family = gaussian)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) -0.28669    0.31211  -0.919   0.3852  
x            0.15290    0.07386   2.070   0.0722 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.1709329)

    Null deviance: 2.1000  on 9  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1.3675  on 8  degrees of freedom
AIC: 14.482

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2


They are both Wald tests.  The column is labelled as t when a variance parameter is estimated and as z when no variance parameter is estimated.
